# Global, network-wide shortcodes or text replace functions

Tags: shortcode, search, text, customization

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple text-replace functions, that would be available to any site in my Wordpress Network. Basically I want to:

1. Change `[--]` into `&mdash;` (—),
2. Be able to link to my own posts using only their titles -- `[internallink post=title]` or anything similar.

I found [simple example of solving this using shortcodes](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-shortcode-display-content-to-registered-users-only).  But I don't know, where to put my custom shortcodes definition, so it would be available to any site in my Wordpress Network.

I'm always looking into solutions as simple as possible, so I would like to know, if I have to use shortcodes to solve these two tasks or:

1. Is there an easy way to define global search & replace mechanism, so any occurence of just `--` would be changed to `&mdash;` in any post or page on any site in the network?
2. Is there anyway to define global shortcode function, that would convert any `[post title]` into link poiting to post titled "Post Title"?

Thank you in advance for any help here?

Comment: Part of what you are doing is already handled by [`wptexturize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a Network enabled shortcode, you only need a [**Must Use plugin**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). Just create the folder `/wp-content/mu-plugins` and drop your code there. From the Codex:

> - Always-on, no need to enable via admin and users cannot disable by accident.
> - Can be enabled simply by uploading file to the mu-plugins directory, without having to log-in.
> - Loaded by PHP, in alphabetical order, **before normal plugins**, meaning API hooks added in an mu-plugin apply to all other plugins
>     even if they run hooked-functions in the global namespace.

The search and replace issue seems a bit more sensitive and *maybe* this plugin can be of use: [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) and do it only in the `post_content` field. You can also use the filter `the_content`, [search this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badd_filter+%2Bthe_content+is%3Aanswer) for various examples on how to deal with it.